# dynamodb query the attributes, not items

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

This is probably a stupid question, but im new with aws and what i want to do is query the attributes available from a table, with aws cli.

Example, i have this:

```
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "GameConsole",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "GameName",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "Games"
```

What i would like to query would be "GameConsole" and "GameName"

I've tried  `aws dynamodb query --select ALL_ATTRIBUTES --table-name Games` but doesn't seem to work, as it expects a specific value for querying items and not the attributes

Comment: Your example looks like partial response of the command describe-table. That's the best you may get, you need to parse those if you want to filter only AttributeDefinitions/AttributeName

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot

Comment: i thought you got your example response from "describe-table" command. I will write this as an answer - someday someone may need it.

Comment: Bear in mind that with schema-on-read, the best you can do here with a describe call is to retrieve key attribute definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Games
```

may give you the details of your table. You need to parse to filter AttributeDefinitions or AttributeName.

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.Basics.html#WorkingWithTables.Basics.DescribeTable)